# What is the difference between the school and school?

Tags: word-usage

I  have a question.

If someone says, 'I go to the school near the post office'
Is someone a student of the school or just a visitor who looks around the achool? The thing i am not sure is the use of 'the'  in the sentence whether 'the' is used as a specific school whiich is near the post office even the speaker is a student of that school?

Hope I have explained my question clearly. If not please let me know.

And thanking you in advance:-)

Answer (score 1):

If they say "I go to the school near the post office, it implies there is one school near the post office, and they go to that school, and they are speaking to someone who knows what they mean.

If they say "I go to school near the post office", that is more vague and it could be any school within any close distance of a post office. However they probably wouldn't say that. They would probably say "I go to school near a post office".